# Error: Could not find or load main class when i execute my jar file

Tags: java, docker, gradle, classnotfoundexception

I am creating a Docker image for my Java Gradle Project.
In my Docker File as I came to an understanding. Executing the dockerFile using `Gradle docker` creates an image for my docker file ready to be executed. it also creates a jar file for my Gradle project to be executed. 
My docker File is as follows :

```
FROM openjdk:13-jdk-alpine

VOLUME /tmp

ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} ./app.jar

CMD ["java","-jar","app.jar" , "Simulator.NewMain"]
```

and by build.gradle is as follows :

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.8.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.22.1'
     id 'java'
}


allprojects {apply plugin: 'idea'}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName =  'Simulator.NewMain'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {  url "http://streamreasoning.org/maven" }
    maven {  url "http://service.hucompute.org/artifactory/libs-release" }
     maven {  url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexeygrigorev/maven-repo/master/" }
}

docker {
        name "hi"
        dockerfile file('src/docker/Dockerfile')
        copySpec.from(jar).rename(".*","app.jar")
        buildArgs(['JAR_FILE' : "app.jar"])
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'Simulator.NewMain'

        )
          }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    }




dependencies {
    //compile project(':shared')
    compile files('libs/mdsj.jar')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ujmp/ujmp-core
    compile group: 'org.ujmp', name: 'ujmp-core', version: '0.3.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datumbox/lpsolve
    compile group: 'com.datumbox', name: 'lpsolve', version: '5.5.2.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc
    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.7.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge/javaml
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge', name: 'javaml', version: '0.1.7'
    compile group: 'be.abeel', name: 'ajt', version: '2.9'



}
```

My Dockerfile produces a jar file into my docker image called app.jar.
I then try to run this jar file in the image. However each time I try it I stumble upon this error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class NewMain.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NewMain.class
```

the result of executing my `Gradle docker` builds successfully, however running `docker run DockerImage` where DockerImage is the name of my image produces the above error.
I tried to create a jar image myself from the same project and execute it using the `java -cp app.jar`  but i am still getting the same error. 
I also went through the jar file's classes and i found the class I am trying to execute. 
the NewMain class is a simple println class with the following syntax:

```
package Simulator;

public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to overcome the classnotfound error? or the reason it happens? 
P.s: I suspected the reason might be from my JDK version so i updated to JDK13

Comment: Are you able to run the jar file locally, I mean without docker image ?

Comment: I tried it but I still get the same error

Comment: I'd recommend using the jib Gradle plugin, personally

Comment: You are building a fat jar, there is no need to specify the main class. Just run java -jar app.jar

Comment: java is looking for a class named `NewMain.class` (note the additional `.class`). It means that the `META-INF/MANIFEST,MF` has an incorrect `Main-Class: NewClass.class`. Your `build.gradle` is correct, just make sure the jar file is rebuilt correctly.